# Thermodynamics question about space height and temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, air

Little "discussion" happening at our brewery and I'm hoping to get it answered once and for all. We put in a walk in cooler. Some of us think that making the cooler 10' high will make the contents in the lower 8' cooler, because the "hot air will have somewhere to go". Others think that making the cooler 8' high will make it cooler because the cooling units won't have to work as hard and can keep it colder, removing hot air completely. I'm hoping this simple theoretical question will yield us an answer w/o discussion of our cooling and fan power, how much the door is being opened etc, but if I'm wrong please enlighten. Thanks so much!

Comment: Isn't a walk-in cooler a closed space (like a refrigerator)? Why do you speak of removing hot air etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some of us think that making the cooler 10' high will make the contents in the lower 8' cooler, because the "hot air will have somewhere to go".

A walk-in cooler (or refrigerator) would be very inefficient and have cold spots or hot spots unless the air were forced (via fans).  Every cooler I'm aware of that size will have fans to force circulation.

Given that, any hot air inside the cooler already has "somewhere to go".  The fans will force the air to circulate past the cooling coil, giving up its heat.  It also will tend to keep the different portions of the unit at almost the same temperature.  If the fans did not circulate the air effectively, then there might be hot spots at the top.

Any such spots wouldn't make the temperature below lower (or higher), because the cooling system and thermostat run whenever necessary.

> Others think that making the cooler 8' high will make it cooler because the cooling units won't have to work as hard and can keep it colder, removing hot air completely

Once the environment inside is cooled down, heat will continue to enter.  Some exchanges when you open the door, but even without that some heat will penetrate through the insulation.  So the big factor in how much the unit runs will be the quality of the insulation, and the surface area of the unit.  All else being equal, a physically smaller unit will have a bit less surface area and will require less power to cool over time, but there's probably not a huge difference between the sizes you're talking about.